# Trigger jobs in control-m from Rundeck

Tags: devops, rundeck, control-m

I have many jobs configured in control-m which I want to trigger from Rundeck. But am not able to figure out how to do it. 
Like the connection between Jenkins and Rundeck, is there any way we can trigger a particular job in control-m through Rundeck.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The API would be the best way to go but if you just want a quick fix then issuing [commands](https://docs.rundeck.com/2.6.9/manual/commands.html) from Rundeck would get you up and running. You would need to issue the command on a box with a Control.M Agent installed and use the appropriate Control-M utility, e.g. - **ctmorder** will order a job, or **ctmcontb** will add a Control-M condition.

Comment: You mean we can pass commands in Rundeck that will be ran in the control-m server and will be able to run jobs in a particular folder or folders in the same way as we can do from GUI control-m ?

Comment: Yes, ctmorder will force a job to run in Control-M if you execute the command externally.

Answer (score 1):

Calling Control-M jobs (from Rundeck) through [Control-M Automation API](https://controlm.github.io/) CLI seems a good option for you.

A good example is to create a script like [this](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/182453?start=0&tstart=0) and call it from Rundeck (The Script uses Control-M Automation API).

More references:

- Basic CURL [usage](https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest) for API Calls.
- [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) tool, an excellent
  tool to test any API.
- A lot of Control-M API calls [examples](https://github.com/controlm/automation-api-quickstart).

Comment: a little bit more detailed information will good as I am totally new to control-m.

Comment: You can call Control-M API using CURL, a good example is to create a bash script that does that. Here you have a good starting point to use CURL to call any API https://www.baeldung.com/curl-rest. Another excellent tool to test API is Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/)